# Magento Observer not called on event dispatch

Tags: php, magento, events, module

I'm loosing my mind on that, I tried to change config.xml over and over again following other stackoverflow answers, but nothing seems to work for me. I can't understand why my observer method is not called when the event is fired. I also checked if Magento is actually firing that event and it is. Magento cache has also been totally disabled.

So that's config.xml (app/code/local/Shopplat/Referralselltracker/etc/config.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shopplat_Referralselltracker>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Shopplat_Referralselltracker>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
        <controller_front_send_response_after>
            <observers>
                <controller_front_send_response_after_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Shopplat_Referralselltracker_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>onAfterFrontendResponse</method>
                </controller_front_send_response_after_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_send_response_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Observer (app/code/local/Shopplat/Referralselltracker/Model/Observer.php)

```
<?php
class Shopplat_Referralselltracker_Model_Observer {

    public function onAfterFrontendResponse(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        error_log("Event Dispatched");
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: UPDATE: if I put that code on an already working module it works well. If I copy the new module on a new Magento installation it works well. There should be something very wrong with this specific Magento installation.

Comment: UPDATE 2: I reinstalled a fresh copy of Magento and that code simply started to work. Magento's misteries...

Answer (score 0):

Try to place this code in Observer file.

```
<?php
class Shopplat_Referralselltracker_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function onAfterFrontendResponse($observer) {
        echo "Event Dispatched";
        die();
        //error_log("Event Dispatched");
    }
}
```

Comment: Extending Varien_Event_Observer and replacing error_log by echo and die doesn't change the situation. That's a weird situation, I used to implement Observer classes without extending Varien_Event_Observer and always worked like a charm. I'm also using error_log in other classes and it works, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

mention the correct `<module>` in app/code/local/Shopplat/Referralselltracker/etc/config.xml by replacing controller_front_send_response_after_observer with shopplat_referralselltracker_model_observer

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I think that tag is simply an identifier of the event handler, I usually put something descriptive about the event and never had that problem. Seems like there is something more subtle going on...

Comment: in etc/config.xml add the following lines of code  <models>
             <Shopplat_Referralselltracker>
               <class>Shopplat_Referralselltracker_Model</class>
             </Shopplat_Referralselltracker>
           </models>

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't the trick. I resolved by reinstalling a fresh copy of Magento. Thank you.